# Can I Connect Shared Folders Between Windows Servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure, network-share, bluemix

I have 2 servers.

One in Azure and the other in IBM Bluemix, I would like to share the server folder in ibm (`Windows 2008 R2`) and Azure (`Windows 2016 DataCenter`) to create a drive letter.

Or vice versa.

If that is not possible, what would be the best way to transfer 400gb of photos (10million) between servers? But I need a way like Robocopy because every day several photos are deleted or created, so a simple copy of the folder via .zip would be outdated.

The servers are public, access via port 80 works.

*English by Google Translate*

Comment: can the servers "see" each other?

Comment: \\<ip> not working, Already enabled ports on the firewall, on the azure firewall, and nothing

Comment: You really don't want to use SMB over internet. Start by establishing a VPN connection (other than PPTP).

Comment: If you want to share directory between Azure and your local server, port 445 should be open. Your ISP also could block the port.

Comment: Do you want to use Azure File Share or others?

Comment: VPN should do the job for you indeed.